# Pandas matplotlib warning

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to plot the average grade of students based on gender. I was able to break each subject up and plot average based on each however, after the graph shows, I get this error or warning (not sure what it is)

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f31e49753d0>

Please how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Do you have a `plt.show()` at the end of your code? If not, please add it. What you are seeing is not an error, but the name of the graph object.

Comment: Agreed, then I typically close all plots at the very end of the code, I typically use plt.close("all"). But make sure to show or save before closing it.

Comment: Not a warning. What you're seeing is a python representation of the graph axes object. Assuming you're using something similar to jupyter notebooks (cause tagged google colab), if the last line of a cell has a result that is not saved in a variable (e.g. a function call without saving result to a variable), the python representation is displayed to the cell output. A quick check would be to add a `dummy = True` at the end of the cell and execute it. This output should disappear then.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

-your plotting code-
-your plotting code-
-your plotting code-

ax.set_xlabel("gender");
```

That semi colon is the import part

```
your graph without the error code

      ||||
||||  ||||
||||  ||||
||||  ||||
||||  ||||
male  female
```